# NSNotification selector method not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I am using NSNotification to pass value between ViewControllers, but value is not getting passed and when i used breakpoints to check what's going wrong i came to know that the receive notification selector method is not called.
Following is the code what i have written

**AViewController.m**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"speciality" object:nil userInfo:[specialityIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

**BViewCOntroller.m**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveSpecialityId:) name:@"speciality" object:nil];

}

-(void)receiveSpecialityId:(NSNotification *)notificaton
{

    NSString *selectedServiceString=[[notificaton userInfo] valueForKey:@"service"];

    _specialtiyId = selectedServiceString;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"service" object:nil ];
}
```

I am trying to pass value from AViewController to BViewController

I have read all the discussions done previously on this same issue, but none of them solved my issue

Comment: Check please that your `BViewCOntroller.m` initialized before `AViewController.m`

Comment: It is possible that the notification is sent before the new controller reaches the viewWillAppear.
Can you post the method used to sent the notification and the code where you load the 2 controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Dont' add

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveSpecialityId:) name:@"speciality" object:nil];
```

in the `viewDidAppear`. I don't know much objective c but here's the deal in swift:

```
func receiveSpecialityID(notification: NSNotification){

  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(<Theclassinwhichthismethodiswritten without the ()).receiveSpecialityID(_:)), name: "Selected", object: nil)   
 /// DO your thing here..
}
```

Then do a:

```
deinit{
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter().removeObserver

}
```

This should work. Try and let me know!